# Python: Problems with indexing a list of list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, indexing

I have this list of lists:

`mylist=[[1, 2, 4, 8], [16, 32, 64, 128], [256, 512, 1024, 2048]]`

Now I want to create a dictionary that assigns each key the value of the corresponding index in the list.

In this case: `correct_dict={0:1,1:2,2:4,3:8,4:16,...,11:2048}`.

I intend to do it with the following function:

```
def dictionarize3(array):
                dict3={}
                count_var=0
                for i in range(len(array[0]) - 1) :
                    for j in range(len(array[0]) - 1):
                        dict3[count_var]=array[i][j]
                        count_var=count_var+1
                return dict3

dict=dictionarize3(mylist)
```

But this is what I get:
`wrong_dict={0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 4, 3: 16, 4: 32, 5: 64, 6: 256, 7: 512, 8: 1024}`.

So, `len(correct_dict)=12`, while `len(wrong_dict)=9`.

**Question:** What makes me miss all the values that in the list are located in the third column?

Comment: `range(len(array[0]) - 1))` => `range(3)` which is -> `[0,1,2]`. So you are missing the last element

Comment: Yes but if I get rid of the `-1` I get an out of index error.

Comment: Try just `range(len(array[0]))` in the second loop

Comment: Why a `dict` at all? If you simply *flatten* the list, you get a list with the exact same indices and values. E.g. `itertools.chain(*mylist)`.

Comment: In the future, think to dict comprehension: `{i: v for lst in mylist for i, v in enumerate(lst)}`.

Comment: I wish I was that far in learning Python :)

Comment: @FrancescoCastellani: This [**Code like a Pythonista**](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html) is a good read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a corrected version of the function dictionarize3:

```
def dictionarize3(array):
    dict3={}
    count_var=0
    for i in range(len(array)) :
        for j in range(len(array[i])):
            dict3[count_var]=array[i][j]
            count_var=count_var+1
    return dict3
```

You weren't referencing the correct parts. When trying to find the length of the whole array you were finding the length of one of he inside arrays, just a logic error.

*EDIT* As pointed out by decltype_auto, it is not at all idiomatic to have an additional iterative variable which carries out the same function as one already declared in a for loop. I was answering so quickly that I didn't spot it! Has alternative and more efficient code:

```
def dictionarize3(array):
dict3={}
for i in range(len(array)) :
    for j in range(len(array[i])):
        dict3[j]=array[i][j]
return dict3
```

Comment: This works. Why does `j` need to reach a higher index than `i`? Why can't I just have `len(array[0])` for both? I tried it and I got an out of index error. But why?

Comment: Is it because my list of list is like a 3x4 matrix? So, the two lenghts are different? Is it this?

Comment: Why did you indent `return dict3` further? Shouldn't it be in line with the first `for`?

Comment: @FrancescoCastellani my bad, fixing that now.

Comment: @R.Murray OK, you answered the question - no doubt about that. But may I propose that you add my alternative code to your answer? This `for i .. for j`  with an additional counter in the question is plainly not idiomatic.

Comment: @decltype_auto You know what I was answering it so quickly I didn't spot that! I'll add a second solution now.

Answer (score 3):

That's a job for [**itertools.chain**](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain)

```
from itertools import chain

mylist=[[1, 2, 4, 8], [16, 32, 64, 128], [256, 512, 1024, 2048]]

mydict = {i:v for i,v in enumerate(chain(*mylist))}

print(mydict)
```

output:

```
{0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 4, 3: 8, 4: 16, 5: 32, 6: 64, 7: 128, 8: 256, 9: 512, 10: 1024, 11: 2048}
```

> **Question**: What makes me miss all the values that in the list are
>   located in the third column?

```
range(len(array[0]) - 1)
```

is a range that ends 1 before its argument; thus in your case one before 4 - 1 = 3 , thus at index 2, which skips the last elements with inner index 3.

**EDIT**
And that the outer loop

```
for i in range(len(array[0]) - 1) :
```

appeared to work is just coincidence, because the outer list *has* length 3.
what you needed is this:

```
for i in range(len(array)):
```

Your "i" is for the whole outer array, not for its first inner element! :)

Answer (score 2):

A `dict` seems very inappropriate here. A simple flat list would give you the same practical result:

```
[1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024, 2048]
```

Here `lst[0]` is `1` and `lst[11]` is `2048`.

You can flatten the list like so:

```
lst = []
for l in mylist:
   lst.extend(l)
```

or:

```
from itertools import chain
lst = chain(*mylist)  # list(chain(*mylist)) if you don't want an iterator
```

Answer (score 2):

in your case

> len(array[0]) = 4

after

> len(array[0]) - 1 = 3
>
> range(3) = [0, 1, 2]

and you work only with part of list [**1, 2, 4**, 8]

Read about [range](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range)

Answer (score 0):

Easy task for dict comprehension and functional programming style:

```
>>> mylist=[[1, 2, 4, 8], [16, 32, 64, 128], [256, 512, 1024, 2048]]
>>> correct_dict = {k:v for k, v in enumerate(reduce(lambda x,y: x+y, mylist))}
>>> correct_dict
{0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 4, 3: 8, 4: 16, 5: 32, 6: 64, 7: 128, 8: 256, 9: 512, 10: 1024, 11: 2048}
```

Explaining, you take the list, reduce it to a single list with all the values, enumerate it with the corresponding indexes and make a dict comprehension taking the index as key and the list number as values.

Comment: use `functools.reduce` instead

Answer (score 0):

If each list have the same length you can do it like this:

```
d = dict((i1*4+i2, x) for i1, y in enumerate(mylist) for i2, x in enumerate(y))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> mylist=[[1, 2, 4, 8], [16, 32, 64, 128], [256, 512, 1024, 2048]]
>>> l = []
>>> for i in mylist:
        l.extend(i)
>>> dict(zip(range(len(l)), l))
```